# How to define how a menu is shown depending on the screen resolution

Tags: wordpress, menu, responsive-design

I am trying to modify a wordpress template. I am not sure how i change the menu type shown depending on the screen resolution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can style your menus by using simple media queries

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .thisclass {
     color:red;
  }
}
```

In this example, 'thisclass' will have red font if the screen width is less than 600px. You can read more about media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).